# Please guide me how to call a method in LWC

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have a static method in a class from which I am getting a string which is in the form of link. Now when I am trying to pull the same data in the LWC, I am getting the data as undefined.
Can anyone please explain me if I need to perform any conversion in  the logic or I have to add extra logic in JS.

Comment: Can you check if the method has AuraEnabled annotation? Also please add snippets of your class and js

Answer (score 1):

Your Apex method should be annotated with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` to be used with LWC.

Then you can simply import your method in LWC using either `@wire` or imperative Apex.

[Checkout the standard documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method)

Please add your code here if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apex, your static method must have `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` if you wan't to be able to store the data in lwc.